# Reference request: Density of testfunctions in sobolev space $ W^{1}_{0}$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

can someone help me out and name a good source where the following statement ist proven?

$C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ being an open, bounded domain with continuous boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: Do you know Evans book on PDE? This proof is included in Chapter 4.

Comment: Are you sure? In the chapter "4. other ways to represent solutions"? Without reading the whole chapter I am a bit skeptical since sobolev spaces are in only introduced in the following chapter 5... At least in my version of the book.

Comment: For me (and many others), this is the *definition* of $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Which definition do you use?

Comment: Ohh correct. Chapter 5 heh